# Returning an int value from a method java

Tags: java, random, return

I'm pretty new to java, but I'm trying to make a simulation of the finger game, 'Sticks', using my limited knowledge. This may not be the neatest, but if you're going to make a suggestion on me to do something, link a page explaining what that thing is, and I'll read it.

Ok, so the issue comes up basically when I call a method to decide who's turn it is and trying to return the value for the "count" up to 5, but it's not returning to main()

```
public static int TurnCalcBB(int PLH, int PRH, int BRH, int BLH, int Death)
{
    //Attacking with bot Right hand
    Random botAtk = new Random();
    if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 1 && PRH <= 5)
    {
        PRH = BRH + PRH;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your right hand is now at " + PRH);
        return PRH;
    } else if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 0 && PLH <= 5){
        PLH = BRH + PLH;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your left hand is now at " + PLH);
        return PLH;
    }
    return Death;
}
```

Death is there because I was getting an error telling me that I always need to return SOMETHING so I'm returning a static value.

Basically, the problem is getting PLH (player left hand) or PRH (player right hand) to return to main. If I'm not wrong, they should return as their initial variable name (PL, and PR) with the returned value correct? If not, what can I do to fix this?

The code is a lot larger than this, and this issue is happening throughout the whole program, so I'm showing just 1 method and assuming they're all the same issue; the methods are almost all the same.

Also, while I'm typing a question already, is nextInt() the best way to do a random number generator? When I had it as nextInt(1) it was exclusively attacking the left hand, and when I switched it to nextInt(2) now it's attacking both, but occasionally the code... "crashes" (what I mean by crashes is that it generates a number outside of what the If statements are looking for). I obviously need to to generate either a 1 or a 2 (or 0 and 1 if 0 counts).

Comment: "they should return as their initial variable name" can you explain that?

Comment: I recommend to save your random result instead of getting another random result again when the first random int was != 1. Which is probably why you think it's generating a number outside of the if statements.

Comment: `PLH = BRH + PLH;` this should probably be `PLH = BLH + PLH;`, shouldn't it?

Comment: if you have to say what your variables mean in parenthesis, you should probably just change your variable names to what's in the parenthesis

Comment: I have a suspicion ... PLH and the other parameters are passed by value (=copy). If you assign them a new value insinde the method, it will be forgotten when the controlflow exits the method. Of course you can access and modify a class variable in the method.

Comment: regarding `Random.nextInt(foo)`if you want a number that includes 0-foo with foo as a possibility you want `nextInt(foo +1)`

Comment: @Flidor I mean the variable name as it is when its an argument, not a parameter. To your second question, no. This method is specifically used if the bot's right hand is selected randomly. After that it uses another random to select which hand it wants to "attack"

Comment: @Eben so if I want a number from 0-1, nextInt(2) is correct?

Comment: Yes you could also do nextInx()%2 == 0 or nextInx()%2 == 1

Comment: How do you know that what is returned by the method is left- or righthand?

Comment: @Fildor the Dialog box tells what hand is "attacked", but other than that, if the method's would return correctly, then I would know because the value jump in hand x. I have a method that happens after every turn that says the value of all the hands.

Comment: I wanna say that the return issue is caused by the variables having different names... but at the same time, I'm not at the computer I was, so I can't test my theory. If anyone can confirm without me testing, feel free to let me know!

Comment: Yes, `nextInt(2)` gives 0 to 1 inclusive.

Comment: @Eben I keep them in acronyms because I had to type them a lot, so typing playerLeftHand or playerRightHand would take up more time. I simply added what they were in parenthesis for the purpose of other people's understanding what they mean, not for my own benefit. Although, I could have just changed them for when I copy/pasted it to this site, and if that's what you mean, then yeah... I probably should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating random number twice, this is why you can observe "strange" behvior.

```
Random botAtk = new Random();
if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 1 && PRH <= 5) {
  ...
} 
else if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 0 && PLH <= 5) {
  ...
}
```

Try generating random only once:

```
Random botAtk = new Random();
boolean right = botAtk.nextInt(2) == 1; // flip coin only once

if(right && PRH <= 5) {
  ...
} 
else if(!right && PLH <= 5) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This fixes the RNG problem! Thank you very much! I don't know the ins and outs of nextInt() so I didnt stop to think that it A. could be a boolean and make life a little easier, and B. that I am generating 2 numbers. I always thought that it was pre-generated when I instantiated the variable as a random.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to

```
public static Integer TurnCalcBB(int PLH, int PRH, int BRH, int BLH, int Death)
{
    //Attacking with bot Right hand
    Random botAtk = new Random();
    if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 1 && PRH <= 5)
    {
        PRH = BRH + PRH;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your right hand is now at " + PRH);
        return PRH;
    } else if(botAtk.nextInt(2) == 0 && PLH <= 5){
        PLH = BRH + PLH;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your left hand is now at " + PLH);
        return PLH;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**NOTE: make sure you first check for null values where you call this function.**

Comment: It is also traditional to return -1 for this kind of case to indicate a problem. This has the advantage of not using the object autoboxing but the disadvantage of potentially being less clear in intent.

Comment: As a matter of taste, I prefer not to introduce nullchecks where you don't really need them. But that's just personal feeling - you could argue pro and con. Regardless, I have the suspicion that this not the OP's problem.

Comment: This solves an issue that I previously stated I had solved by including a static variable. Nonetheless, if I'm doing it untraditionally, at least I know the traditional way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer will not get accepted, because there is an accepted one, but nevertheless:

I suspect that you have a wrong understanding of method parameter passing in Java.
What I read from your question and comments is that you expect this to work:

```
public static int psInt = 0;

static void main() {
    int someNumber = 1;
    int someOtherNumber = 5;

    method1( someNumber, someOtherNumber );
    // You expect "someNumber" to be 6 right now.
    // But in fact, the value will be unchanged.

    // What WILL work: psInt is 0 now
    method3(); // this method will modify the static class var
    // psInt is 5 now.
}


static void method1( int numParam, int someothervalue ){
   numParam = numParam + someothervalue;
}

static void method2( int someNumber, int someothervalue ){
   someNumber = someNumber + someothervalue; // <- same name won't work either!
}

public static void method3(){ 
     psInt = 5; 
}
```

But in Java method arguments are passed by value. That is: a copy!
So no matter how you name the variables and arguments, you will never have an "out" argument here.

What you **can** do:

1. In a static method, you can use and modify static class variables.
2. In a non-static method, you can use and modify non-static and static class variables.
3. You can pass a State-Object, of which you can modify field values.
4. You can return a value.
5. ... there are more possibilites. These just to start with.

In your case, 4. does not make so much sense, because you wouldn't know if it is the new right or left hand value.

Comment: Within the if-statement I have it output what the value of the effected hand is. If you mean the other way around (I dont know which hand is attacking) that's true, but I could let myself know by having it tell me which hand is picked, just like the other ones. Even still, this doesn't help me fix the issue I'm having with the values not returning.  It's not that I think it'll work, its just that I don't know if it will. I do have a question for you based on your answer though. That is, if I return a variable of the same name, will it return the value of the hand?

Comment: Let me clarify the above comment. I mean if I were to keep the variable PL, like it is in main(), instead of PLH would it return like it should?

Comment: No. You simply cannot modify a local var in that setup. As soon as you call that static method and pass the variables, the variables will be copied and the copies used during execution of the method. The originals won't be touched. If the variables are static class variables, you don't need to pass them. Just use them in the method and they will reflect the modifications.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to show me how to do it!